# How to modify the Table of Contents to add the words Chapter, Appendix, Figure, Table

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats

I am trying to get the words Chapter, Appendix, Figure and Table into the table of contents.  The thesis requirements can be found here http://www.usc.edu/schools/GraduateSchool/documents/Thesis/Format_Presentation_Guidelines.pdf.  The relavent part of the guidelines is the fact that the words Chapter, Appendix, Figure and Table must appear on the same line as the item.  For example (please note that the major chapters/Tables/Figures/Appendicies have double spacing while the subsections have single spacing).

Thanks in advance for the help!

## Dedication   ii

## Acknowledgments  iii

## Abstract   xxiv

## Chapter 1:  Some title....4

### 1.1  MySection First Name....3

### 1.2  MySection Second Name....5

## Chapter 2: MyChapter Two Title

## Appendices

## Appendix A: Why I love Research ....10

### A.1 Preliminaries..........10

### A.2 More Preliminaries......11

## Appendix B: Why I Need Friends that Know Latex ....13

### B.1 Preliminaries.......14

### B.2 More Priliminaries....15

## List of Figures

## Figure 1.1: My first figure......15

## Figure 1.2: My first figure......15

## Figure 2.1: My first figure......25

## Figure 2.2: My first figure......25

## List of Tables

## Table 1.1: My Table......15

## Table 1.2: My Table......17

## Table 2.1: My Table......25

## Table 2.2: My Table......27

Note: The outline above does not show the spacing required.  The major chapters need to be double spaced while the subsection should be single spaced. The packages used and the document format follows.

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[dissertation,final]{USCthesis}
%NOTE: THE def \degree WAS REDEFINED from \degree to \degreeName IN ORDER TO AVOID %CONFLICTS WITH THE siunitx PACKAGE.  NOTE: THE STYLE FILE USCthesis WAS CHANGED. ALL 2 OCCURANCES OF \degree WAS CHANGED TO \degreeName SO AS NOT TO CONFLICT WITH siunitx package.  

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

\usepackage{subfigure} % Written by Steven Douglas Cochran
  % This package makes it easy to put subfigures
  % in your figures. i.e., "figure 1a and 1b"
  % Docs are in "Using Imported Graphics in LaTeX2e"
  % by Keith Reckdahl which also documents the graphicx
  % package (see above). subfigure.sty is already
  % installed on most LaTeX systems. The latest version
  % and documentation can be obtained at:
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}%used for professional tables
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%used to add color to tables
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%Used for script math fonts
\usepackage{bm}%\bm{\omega} produces bold omega
\usepackage{amsbsy}%\boldsymbol{\omega} also produces bold omega
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[load-configurations = version-1]{siunitx}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{standalone}%Use to generate tikz pictures from separate LaTeX code for each graphic

%\nofiles
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\title{SOME TITLE}         % ALL CAPS in title. The title needs to be double spaced to be compliant with USC guidelines
\author{WILEY COYOTE} % For example, Tommy Trojans. Only the first letter of each word requires CAPS.

\submitdate{May 2012}              % Officially, submitdate can only be May, August and December.
\begin{preface}
\prefacesection{Dedication}             % (Optional) Dedication
Blah blah blah
\prefacesection{Acknowledgments}
I would like to thank....
\tableofcontents                        % List of contents
\listoftables                           % List of tables
%\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{Table }
%\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{}
\listoffigures                          % List of figures

\include{thesis_abs}                    % Abstract: thesis_abs.tex starts with \prefacesection{Abstract}

\end{preface}

\include{Chapter1}%Include the file named "Chapter1
\include{Chapter2}% Include the file named "Chapter2
\include{Chapter3}%Include the file named "Chapter3
\begin{singlespace}                     % single-space for bibliography
\references[Bibliography]{IEEEtranS}{../Dissertation_bib} %Include a bibliography file named "Dissertation_bib" located in the relative directory.... Use IEEEtranS to sort bibliography by last name of first author. 

\begin{appendices}
 \include{Appendix}%Includes the appendix file named "Appendix"
\end{appendices}
\end{singlespace}
\printindex% There is an index file in my thesis that is generated by xindy
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should look at these [templates](http://www.gradschool.sc.edu/thesisdissertation/dissertation-latex.htm) to use `uscthesis` class. The way your code is, I personally feel that it would make a big mess for you. The sample files in the link provided have all the features you are asking for and you can get them by using that class. The web page mentioned above also has guidelines for how to use the `uscthesis` class.

PS: It is better to use a style file/class as directed / provided by your university than manually trying to tweak the things by yourself (which will avoid any troubles to you).